# How Export and Import Function between Controllers Adonis js

Tags: node.js, controller, adonis.js

I have the controller number one

```html
'use strict'

class Controller1 {
    async sum() {
        let a = 10
        let b = 2

        return a * b
    }
}

module.exports = Controller1
```

and in the second controller i have this

```html
'use strict'
const Controller1 = use('App/Controllers/Http/Controller1')

class Controller2 {
   async othersum() {
       const sum = Controller1.sum()

       return sum + 50
    }
}

module.exports = Controller2
```

How is the call in other function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Controller1.sum()` is not an static method,
you need to create an instance of **Controller1** to use `sum()` method

```
'use strict'
const Controller1 = use('App/Controllers/Http/Controller1')

class Controller2 {
   async othersum() {
       const ctrl = new Controller1()
       const sum = ctrl.sum()

       return sum + 50
    }
}

module.exports = Controller2
```